# Implemanting / Integrating google voice action / google assistant in my app

Tags: android, action, actions-on-google, voice

I have developed an app which shows users Facts, News, Jokes and all such interesting information in a very few word when they get bored.

Now i want that if user ask like 
"OK Google i am bored" or "OK google tell/show me some interesting fact", if my app is installed on that device assistant should suggest my app to user and if user says yes assistant should open my app.

I have seen google Voice Action documentation but it confused me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [app actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/), which are not yet in developer preview but were announced at I/O earlier this year.

You can [get notified](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfzg7DrFtD8S_tHrYYoWpmsfFzLuduukoQQY6A2AtHsxTHgKg/viewform) when App actions will be available.

From the Android Developers Documentation:

> With App Actions, your app can be recommended to users as a way to
>   fulfill their needs - at the moment they need it the most. By
>   registering your app to handle one or more user intents, users will be
>   able to see and interact with your app across multiple Google and
>   Android surfaces.

Comment: Thanks prisoner,it clearly fit my need hope they will launch it soon. But is there any other option you know